# Recording result of audio processed from a buffer and placing it in an audio element

Tags: audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api, mediastream, webkitaudiocontext

I have a JavaScript file that takes an audio file, places it in a buffer and then allows the audio in the buffer to be processed (by changing the speed and loop duration).

I wish to record the resulting audio, including the manipulation, and place it in an `<audio>` element. I have tried to do this by integrating the code given in the first answer here:

[Record sound of a webaudio api's audio context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234902/record-sound-of-a-webaudio-apis-audio-context)

with my JavaScript file. However, I get the following errors when I press the play button (which should also start the recording):

```
GET http://localhost:8000/[object%20AudioBufferSourceNode] [HTTP/1.0 404 File not found 1ms] 

HTTP load failed with status 404. Load of media resource http://localhost:8000/[object%20AudioBufferSourceNode] failed. index.html

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable.
```

I believe I am not hooking up the media recorder correctly. Can anybody assist?

Thank you,

My html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title>decodeAudioData example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>decodeAudioData example</h1>

    <button class="play">Play</button>
    <button class="stop">Stop</button>

    <h2>Set playback rate</h2>
    <input class="playback-rate-control" type="range" min="0.25" max="3" step="0.05" value="1">
    <span class="playback-rate-value">1.0</span>

    <h2>Set loop start and loop end</h2>
    <input class="loopstart-control" type="range" min="0" max="20" step="1" value="0">
    <span class="loopstart-value">0</span>

    <input class="loopend-control" type="range" min="0" max="20" step="1" value="0">
    <span class="loopend-value">0</span>

    <br>
    <br>

    <!--Audio recoring destination element-->
    <audio id='recording' controls='true'></audio>

  </body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript is:

```
let audioCtx;
let source;
let songLength;

const pre = document.querySelector('pre');
const myScript = document.querySelector('script');
const play = document.querySelector('.play');
const stop = document.querySelector('.stop');

const playbackControl = document.querySelector('.playback-rate-control');
const playbackValue = document.querySelector('.playback-rate-value');
playbackControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

const loopstartControl = document.querySelector('.loopstart-control');
const loopstartValue = document.querySelector('.loopstart-value');
loopstartControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

const loopendControl = document.querySelector('.loopend-control');
const loopendValue = document.querySelector('.loopend-value');
loopendControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

// Recording variables

var recorder=false;
var recordingstream=false;

// use XHR to load an audio track, and
// decodeAudioData to decode it and stick it in a buffer.
// Then we put the buffer into the source

function getData() {
  /*if(window.webkitAudioContext) {
    audioCtx = new window.webkitAudioContext();
  } else {
    audioCtx = new window.AudioContext();
  }*/
  audioCtx = new window.AudioContext();

  source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', 'precky.mp3', true);

  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';


  request.onload = function() {
    let audioData = request.response;

    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
        myBuffer = buffer;
        songLength = buffer.duration;
        source.buffer = myBuffer;
        source.playbackRate.value = playbackControl.value;
        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        source.loop = true;

        loopstartControl.setAttribute('max', Math.floor(songLength));
        loopendControl.setAttribute('max', Math.floor(songLength));
      },

      function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.error});

  }

  request.send();
}


function startrecording(){
    recordingstream=audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
    recorder=new MediaRecorder(recordingstream.stream);
    recorder.start();
}

function glue(){
    let a=new Audio(source);
    let mediasource=audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(a);
    mediasource.connect(recordingstream);//connects also to MediaRecorder
    a.play();
} 

function stoprecording(){
  recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable',function(e){
   document.querySelector('#recording').src=URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
   recorder=false;
   recordingstream=false;
  });
  recorder.stop();
    } 

// wire up buttons to stop and play audio, and range slider control

play.onclick = function() {
  getData();
  source.start(0);
  play.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  playbackControl.removeAttribute('disabled');
  loopstartControl.removeAttribute('disabled');
  loopendControl.removeAttribute('disabled');
  startrecording();
  glue(source);

}

stop.onclick = function() {
  source.stop(0);
  play.removeAttribute('disabled');
  playbackControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  loopstartControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  loopendControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  stoprecording();

}


playbackControl.oninput = function() {
  source.playbackRate.value = playbackControl.value;
  playbackValue.innerHTML = playbackControl.value;
}

loopstartControl.oninput = function() {
  source.loopStart = loopstartControl.value;
  loopstartValue.innerHTML = loopstartControl.value;
}

loopendControl.oninput = function() {
  source.loopEnd = loopendControl.value;
  loopendValue.innerHTML = loopendControl.value;
}
```

The original decodeAudioData example (without my attempt to record) comes from Mozilla docs here:
https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/decode-audio-data/ by chrisdavidmills

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but I took your sample code and created this fiddle with it.  It works, once I replaced your "precky.mp3" with something that's available to me.  See https://jsfiddle.net/rtoy/2wx967qc/4/

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I've just tried it at the Fiddle location you've give. The sine wave you've used plays and the audio element shows duration once the stop button is pressed but when you then try to play the audio element there is no sound. This is the same as I have been experiencing. The console in Fiddle is showing no errors, though. After my post yesterday I added   source.connect(recordingstream); in the startrecording() function in-between recordingstream=audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination(); and
    recorder=new MediaRecorder(recordingstream.stream); It works but the same errors show.